# Where can I see the generated class file for my java source code in Domino Designer?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib, domino-designer-eclipse

After creating a new java class and saving it(built automatically) in Domino Designer, I was not able to see the the correspondingly generated `.class` file in the default path `WebContent\WEB-INF\classes`.

Actually I was unable to find this folder in Java perspective under Package Explorer window.

Anybody knows how can I see these class files?
Thanks a lot!

PS:  I uploaded the image about the Project Explorer view, but there are only .jar files shown there and all the folders can not be unfolded.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the **Navigator** view in Domino Designer. You can add it with menu "Windows / Show Eclipse Views / Navigator".

[image]

You can find all generated class files in folder "WebContent/WEB-INF/classes" then.

Comment: Thanks Knut, I got it as you said!

Answer (score 2):

You can find them in the Project Explorer view, but you'll need to click on the Menu icon at the top of the Project Explorer view and remove the filter that hides .class files. Then they will be visible.

I'm not sure of the use case for viewing them. They can't really be viewed, they're compiled from the Java classes in the Local source folder on a build and get cleared by a clean. They're not of any use outside Domino. And any changes to an XPage overwrites any amendments made directly in the Local folder, which will also overwrite any the source files.

Comment: @ Paul. Thanks Paul. I did open the Project Explorer view as you said, but there are only .jar file shown there and all the folders can not be unfolded. I uploaded the image about the Project Explorer view. Could you tell me what's wrong with it? Thanks.

Comment: and there is no WebContent\WEB-INF\classes folders shown in the Project Explorer view. Pretty weird.

Comment: I tried all different customized filter options, but the WebContent\WEB-INF\classes folder and the .class files did not appear.